# pywinauto install fail in Win10 Pro

Tags: pip, windows-10, pywinauto

Cannot find pywinauto --
Install worked ok last year while in Win7.
This week upgraded to Win10, and install fails

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\paul-lap>pip --version
pip 20.3.3 from c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:\Users\paul-lap>python --version
Python 3.8.5

C:\Users\paul-lap>pip install pywinauto
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 
   'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pywinauto/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywinauto
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywinauto
```

Comment: Solved it-- re-Downloaded Python, this time 3.9.1.  Then tried  pip install pywinauto  and it worked.  Case closed.